# Use 'Bootstrap' theme

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to change PrimeNG theme in an Angular 6 app with no success.

This is from `angular.json` - I am trying to use the "Bootstrap" theme:

```
...
styles": [
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/redmond/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
...
```

But the theme didn't change to "Bootstrap" style:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PrimeNg used to have some free themes. One of them was a Bootstrap theme. It was different from Bootstrap, but just had Bootstrap-like look and didn't require Bootstrap as a dependency.

At the time of writing this answer, PrimeNG 6.1.0 has deprecated all free themes except `nova` theme with three variations `nova-colored`, `nova-light` and `nova-dark`.

[image]

To apply PrimeNG free theme, just import theses files in your `style.css`:

```
@import url("../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css");
@import url("../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-colored/theme.css");
@import url("../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css");
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-themes)

In old versions of PrimeNG 5.x, we could apply the Bootstrap theme like this:

```
@import url("../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css");
@import url("../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css");
```

**UPDATE:**

PrimeNG old free themes are no longer maintained after [PrimeNG 6.1.0 is released](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6-1-0-rc1-nova/):

> Free themes prior to 6.1 are now deprecated and will not be maintained
>   anymore as they were outdated and hard to maintain due to their
>   implementation. With 6.1.0, whether free or premium, all themes
>   offered will be developed by PrimeNG Theme Designer. This will help us
>   maintain all themes from a central location.

Comment: Could you provide some reference on PrimeNG announcement for deprecating all free themes except the Nova flavors for completeness, please?

Comment: Thank you! I've also edited your answer to fix some language\formatting. Hopefully, you'd like my changes :)